# Call private method of object from callback

Tags: javascript

This is a javascript best practice question. I have an immediately executed function that stops me from polluting the global object, and lets me create private and public methods.

What I'm stuck on, is.. If in one of the private methods (`drawChart` below), how to handle having a call-back that changes `this` to something else, but still be able to call another private method within the module... The example below shows what I mean - how can I make sure that `addChartSummay` is always executed with the correct `this` ?

```
var SentDetails = (function () {
    var chart;

    var addChartSummary = function () {

        // In here, I need to access "chart"
        chart.something = something;

    };

    var drawChart = function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            ...
        }, function(chart) {
            // Because this is in a oncomplete call-back, "this" is now set to window (global)
            addChartSummary(); // Will enter method but "this" is wrong so will not work
            SentDetails.addChartSummary.call(..); // Won't work because addChartSummary is private..


        });
    };

    return {
        loadChart: function() {
            ... do some work
            drawChart();
        }
    }

}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the object to a variable outside of the functions.  The nested functions will form a closure containing the outer function.

```
var that = this;

var addChartSummary = function () {

    // In here, I need to access "chart"
    that.chart.something = something;

};

var drawChart = function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        ...
    }, function(chart) {
        that.addChartSummary.call(..); 

    });
};
```

Comment: That's a pretty simple solution, I like it :)